# Django - suing font awersome in unicode form

Tags: django, font-awesome

I want to use font awersome in my project in the way, that user can choose which icon he wants. I found [django-fontawesome-5](https://github.com/BenjjinF/django-fontawesome-5) but there is one problem - there is no access to icon's unicode and I need it for one javascript component (html doesn't work there, and unicode does). I was looking all over the internet, but I coundn't find anything that would allow me to add font-awersome icons, with their unicodes somhow stored. My question is do you know how to get this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unicode codes are stored in [icons.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BenjjinF/django-fontawesome-5/master/fontawesome_5/icons.json) and in [icons_semantic_ui.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BenjjinF/django-fontawesome-5/master/fontawesome_5/icons_semantic_ui.json)

Since you've got the codes source you can define a custom templatetag or a model/mixin method  or a function which just gets a code from one of those json files using icon name

You can see example in [fontawesome_5/utils.py](https://github.com/BenjjinF/django-fontawesome-5/blob/master/fontawesome_5/utils.py)